# Can't get epoch time to pass in form post

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form that runs a php script in the background on button push
The problem is that when I use the form on a iPad the response is cached
This is solvable by making the post data unique and I want to do this by adding a hidden field which contains the current epoch time.

Currently I use :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $("#myform").append(data.datum);
                var datum = Date.getTime();
                $('input[name=datum]').val(datum);
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this does not seem to work :(

Comment: fixed it by putting no-cache headers in the POST location and dont need the epoch time anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the two lines that deal with the date *before* you post the data e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            var datum = Date.getTime();
            $('input[name=datum]').val(datum);
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $("#myform").append(data.datum);
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried that and then the post completely stops working.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by putting no-cache headers in the POST location and dont need the epoch time anymore